# Shall i have multiple include: in spf records in DNS TXT entry

Tags: dns, spf

I need to know the syntax of TXT records for spf.  I added spf records in my domain DNS entries as following example,

> v=spf1 a mx include:abc.com include:bcd.com ~all , ttl : 14400 Done!

Here i used 2 include:, will it create any problem.  And what should be the ttl time, here i have 14400 and seems not a perfect timings.

Please suggest me the ttl timings and how many include: can i able to use in single spf1 records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

2 includes will not cause any problems. [RFC 7208 - SPF - 4.6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.4):

> Some mechanisms and modifiers (collectively, "terms") cause DNS
> queries at the time of evaluation, and some do not.  The following
> terms cause DNS queries: the "include", "a", "mx", "ptr", and
> "exists" mechanisms, and the "redirect" modifier.  SPF
> implementations MUST limit the total number of those terms to 10
> during SPF evaluation, to avoid unreasonable load on the DNS.

In your case, you could technically have 8 includes since you're already using `a` and `mx` terms.

The good TTL time will depend on your situation. You might want to lower it if you have migrations in the few next days and increase it otherwise. In your case, it's set to 4 hours, which is decent. Take a look at this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/7478/recommended-dns-ttl) for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208 where they say the DNS protocol limit is 512 octet.

As for the syntax, see http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax and note the only TTL is the resource record's one (i.e. there is no ttl parameter as part of SPF).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can this is not an issue. you can also more then two. Write this in your spf txt records with your domain name.

```
 v=spf1 include:mail.first.net include:mail.second.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

You can check this spf is valid or not with this [tool](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action).
you also validated your domain before setting plesae [use this](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?).